# Why Docker doesn't see my entrypoint if container include it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

need some help. I tried to set up the first Docker image of my Django project, but docker doesn't see my entrypoint script. At first, I started my compose by
`sudo docker-compose up -d --build` but localhost steel empty. So I run `sudo docker-compose logs -f`

Here are the logs.

```
Attaching to djangopetgeo_db_1, djangopetgeo_web_1
db_1   | 2020-12-02 18:56:07.093 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-12-02 18:56:07.093 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-12-02 18:56:07.102 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-12-02 18:56:07.138 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-12-02 18:54:46 UTC
db_1   | 2020-12-02 18:56:07.150 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | Waiting for postgres...
web_1  | /usr/src/djangoPetGeo/entrypoint.sh: 7: /usr/src/djangoPetGeo/entrypoint.sh: nc: not found
```

Docker doesn't saw my entrypoint as I said. But in this screen, u can see I had entrypoint.sh inside my web app.

[Screen with terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMX8T.png)

Here is my Dockerfile.

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.6-slim

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/djangoPetGeo

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib gcc python3-dev musl-dev libgdal-dev gdal-bin

ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# copy project
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/djangoPetGeo/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: ./djangoPetGeo
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./djangoPetGeo/:/usr/src/djangoPetGeo/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=8596dbPASS
      - POSTGRES_DB=pet_geo_db
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Someone help me pls.

Comment: It's finding and running the entrypoint script, but isn't finding a support tool `nc` (possibly named "netcat").

Comment: Please share your entrypoint script. As David said, it is 99.9% because of `nc` not being installed in your image. Try adding `apt install -y netcat` to your Dockerfile.

Comment: So I installed netcat and now it actually works. Ty so much